# Element 'group' does not match any field or property of class Gillie.JobCenter.Domain.KeyValueEntity

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

can someone help me? i spend a lot of time to resolving this problem and nothing

**this is structure of mongodb collection:**
[image]

**this is my entity and helped objects:**

```
public class Course
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    [BsonElement("_etag")]
    public ObjectId Etag { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("group")]
    public KeyValueEntity<string> Group { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("values")]
    public GroupValuesCourse[] Values { get; set; }
}

public class KeyValueEntity<T>
{
    [BsonElement("key")]
    [JsonProperty("key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("value")]
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value?.ToString();
    }
}
public class GroupValuesCourse
{
    [BsonElement("group")]
    public KeyValueEntity<string> GroupKeys { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("values")]
    public KeyValueEntity<string>[] ValueKeys { get; set; }
}
```

**And my repository**

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<KeyValueEntity<string>>> GetAllForGroupAsync(string groupName, string subGroupName)
    {
        return await mongoDbContext.MongoDataBase.GetCollection<Course>("courses").AsQueryable()
            .Where(courseGroup => courseGroup.Group.Value == groupName)
                .SelectMany(courseGroups => courseGroups.Values)
                .Where(subgroup => subgroup.GroupKeys.Value == subGroupName)
                    .SelectMany(groups => groups.ValueKeys)
                    .OrderBy(value => value.Value)
                    .ToListAsync();
    }
```

And after execution this tell me that:System.FormatException: Element 'group' does not match any field or property of class Gillie.JobCenter.Domain.KeyValueEntity`1[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].
But i'm sure that mapping is correct. Can someone help me to find mistake?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Comment: @DimaGrigoriev no you don't. By posting this on Stack Overflow you agreed to publicly license this, thereby rendering your claim on this post void.

Comment: No, you don't. There are users which have put time and effort to write decent answers.

Comment: You can always ask to have this post disassociated from your account; use the [Contact Us](http://stackoverflow.com/contact) form for this.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like Course.Group is null for some courses.  Perhaps filter out somehow.  I've added a where clause to get rid of them as an example.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<KeyValueEntity<string>>> GetAllForGroupAsync(string groupName, string subGroupName)
{
    return await mongoDbContext.MongoDataBase.GetCollection<Course>("courses").AsQueryable()
        .Where(courseGroup => courseGroup.Group != null)
        .Where(courseGroup => courseGroup.Group.Value == groupName)
            .SelectMany(courseGroups => courseGroups.Values)
            .Where(subgroup => subgroup.GroupKeys.Value == subGroupName)
                .SelectMany(groups => groups.ValueKeys)
                .OrderBy(value => value.Value)
                .ToListAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented by own using this little hack. I've used Select and First instead of SelectMany, and it's work now. As i'm understood mongodbDriver don't support hard quties like this. So it's my result

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<KeyValueEntity<string>>> GetAllForGroupAsync(string groupName, string subGroupName)
    {
        return async coursesCollection.AsQueryable()
             .Where(courseGroup => courseGroup.Group.Value == groupName)
                .SelectMany(courseGroups => courseGroups.Values)
                    .Where(subGroup => subGroup.GroupKeys != null)
                    .Where(subgroup => subgroup.GroupKeys.Value == subGroupName)
                        .Select(groups => groups.ValueKeys)
                        .FirstAsync();
    }
```

Comment: It's still actual question